# Codename One - back Command

Tags: java, codenameone

I built my forms using the GUI builder, but I am trying to implement the navigation buttons in code. I want the app to look similar in Android and Iphone, and am having a hard time trying to make the Back Buttons work.

So I ended up deciding to use the Toolbar (also because I need 1 Icon and 3 buttons on my Main form). Now, the app looks the same in both Android and IOS.

The problem is that **when I add the Back Command to the Toolbar**, the Android hardware button does not work. If I don't use the toolbar, the button works well, but the looks are different.

**Could you check if this is an issue?**

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it worked with the hardware buttons and all. I'll need a more accurate sample/test case of what's not working:

```
    final Form hi = new Form("First");
    Button test = new Button("Test");
    test.addActionListener((e) -> {
        Form newForm = new Form("Bye");
        newForm.setToolbar(new Toolbar());
        newForm.setBackCommand(new Command("Back") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                hi.showBack();
            }
        });
        newForm.show();
    });
    hi.show();
```

Comment: I don¡t know where to put that, so I created a new project, added a button, pressed "Action Event" to that button and added the code. Then I run the simulator, I press the button, the new form "First" gets created and the Back Button does not work for me. Not sure if I did something wrong

Comment: How do you add the back command to the toolbar in the GUI builder application? It should be added implicitly.